# What's the best way to test a package created with vite.js?

Tags: typescript, npm, vite, lib

I'm creating a package writen is TS with vite.js lib feature.

I'm using workspace (mono-repo) feature of npm and my project structure is like that:

```
MyPackage
- apps
  - my-package-example
    - package2.json
- packages
  - my-package
    - package3.json
package1.json
```

`my-package` folder is used to store my package source files and `my-package-example` folder is a vite.js website used to test my package.

package2.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-package-example",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "i": "rm -rf node_modules && yarn",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "realt-commons": "../../packages/my-package",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

package3.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "private": false,
  "version": "1.1.3",
  "type": "module",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "module": "./dist/my-package.es.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/my-package.js",
      "require": "./dist/my-package.umd.js"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "build:watch": "vite build --watch",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Currently to test my package in my example website i need to:

1. `yarn build:watch` in `my-package` folder (to auto rebuild package on changes)
2. `yarn i` in `my-package-example` folder (because modules file changes are not updated (why?))
3. `yarn dev` in `my-package-example` folder (to restart vite.js server)

Repeat 2 and 3 everytime I modify something in my package.

This is clearly not a optimize way to proceed.
Do you know what's the best way to handle that ?

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Look for `yarn link` that symlinks your package forler rather then copy the build

Comment: Hi @Dimava,
Thanks for your answer.

It seems to work, I'll have to see if it's a problem in the future.

Comment: feel free to write an answer